# Sed: how to replace 0 and :?

Tags: sed

```
sed -i s:group\:\:000::g  myfile 
/usr/local/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 12: number option to `s' command may not be zero
```

I want to replace the string group::000 with nothing,i tried to escape with \
but doens't work.

Comment: `sed -i s/group::000//g file` works for me, but you have not included any information about the input file, so that is not guaranteed to work...

Comment: Qoute your `sed` expression: `sed 's:group\:\:000::g'`

Comment: +1 to the answer and comments: @elbarna, you're getting too tricky with alternate s/// delimiters. Keep it simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace the string group::000 with nothing,

That translates to `s/group::000//g`

And this 
`sed -i s/group::000//g myfile`

should do the trick.